# How do I make an ore kill someone when they touch it?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Im trying to make a scavenger hunt for my friend and I want to make an ore kill her when she picks it up

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the ore. But assuming we are talking vanilla minecraft:

Redstone ore has the interesting property that is emits a signal when steped on or otherwise interacted with. So you could simply place a command block right next to it and have that execute whoever you want killed.

Comment: Your answer is either inaccurate or unclear. Redstone ore does not emit a redstone signal directly, it only emits particles, but this can be detected using a BUD or the observer block.

Answer (score 0):

You could detect if she had any of the "bad" ore in her inventory via the following command.

```
/clear playername ore_name -1 0
```

Replace playernamr with your friend's name and "ore_name" with the name of the bad ore (coal, redstone, iron_ore, etc.)

Put that command into a repeating-aways-on command block leading into a chain-conditional-always-on command_block with this command

```
/kill playername
```

This will make it so that if the first command completes successfully, the second command is run, killing the player.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that by downloading the [Fake Ores mod](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-mods/2461487-1-7-10-1-13-2-fake-ores-ores-become-alive-now), which you can download [at Curseforge](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/fake-ores).

> This mod will add fake ores in your Minecraft world. When you break a fake ore, it becomes alive and then attacks you. All fake ores may drops some items that allows you to craft the Ores Boss spawner. A cup spawn when you kill the Ores Boss.

Comment: Can you explain what the mod in the link actually does? If that link dies for some reason, your answer just becomes "You can do that by downloading mods".

Comment: InfiniteEnternitis, I've gone head and updated your answer to include the name and description of the mod, along with direct link to the download page. When suggesting a mod as solution, I'd suggest always including this information. Cheers.

Comment: The Original person mentioned how they're playing on Bedrock Edition. Curseforge mods are only for Java Edition if I could recall correctly, so this answer may end up being misleading to other Bedrock Edition players. Could you clarify in your answer that it would only apply to Java Edition?